# Segmentation Fault For Binary Search In C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search

I am writing code for a given array of 10, and use binary search to find the location, but when I run that, there is always a Segmentation fault.
I viewed others' codes, but I can't find any significant difference.
I could really use some help, thanks a lot. Here's my code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binary(int arr[], int start, int end, int target) {
  int mid = (end - start) / 2;

  if (arr[mid] == target) {
    return mid;
  }
  if (arr[mid] < target) {
    if (mid < end) return binary(arr, mid + 1, end, target);
  } else if (arr[mid] > target) {
    if (mid > start) return binary(arr, start, mid - 1, target);
  }
  return -1;
}

int main(void) {
  int arr[10] = {1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, 50, 65, 82};
  int num, location;
  scanf("%i", &num);
  location = binary(arr, 0, 9, num);
  printf("%i", location);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mid = (end - start) / 2;` should be `mid = (start + end) / 2;`  You want the midpoint, not the offset of the midpoint from `start`.

Comment: Also, this is not a recursive problem.  Using recursion will only serve to waste stack space and slow it down.  It's also less concise.  HInt:  Use a `while` loop.

Comment: there are two ways to solve the issue that you have.
clearly, it's with the calculation of mid-index, you can do as @TomKarzes mentioned or `mid = start + (end-start)/2;`